# Why add "+" and double quotes to access the object's src?

Tags: javascript

When the mouse over the *preview* class image, the #image div will display the image instead of the original plain text. 
The JavaScript function works well. I have a question about using `document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url('"+previewPic.src+"')";` to get the parameter’s url.

Why have to add *"* and *+* before `previewPic.src`? `console.log(previewPic.src)` will display the image’s url, but I tried to use `"url('previewPic.src')"` to access the url, it doesn’t work. What’s the reason?

Demo at: http://codepen.io/betty-Liu/pen/GoxLpb

```
<body>
    <div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>
    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" >
</body>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage="url('"+previewPic.src+"')";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt; 
}
```

Comment: Uh... because `"url('previewPic.src')"` is a string, `"url('"+previewPic.src+"')"` is putting the variable in the string? This is really, really basic stuff =/

Comment: `"url('previewPic.src')"` is a string. JavaScript doesn't know that *you* intended `previewPic.src` to be evaluated as JavaScript and access the `src` property of the `previewPic` variable. I mean, consider `var foo = 42; console.log("foo");`. What would *you* to expect to be the output?

Answer (score 2):

Erm, that's just string concatenation and is used to join strings together including variables and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `backgroundImage` property to set a [CSS `background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) requires to use the `url()` notation. You have to put the URL between the brackets. To assemble it, you concatenate it with the variable holding the URL, using the `+` operator:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + picture.src + ")";
```

You don’t need to use quotes within `url()`, however, you may. In both CSS and JavaScript, they are interchangeable, meaning `"url('/img.jpg')"` is equivalent to `'url("/img.jpg")'`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @BBear: I’m glad it helped, because both [`url()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/url) and [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) are very useful and powerful. Make sure to know [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

object.style.backgroundImage="url('URL')", "url('URL')" is a string. 
url() is part of the string you want to assgin, so use + to concatenate